# Как правильно поместить файл .h в файл modulemap?

Tags: swift, xcode, native

У меня есть статическая библиотека с несколькими файлами .h в качестве API, структура каталогов выглядит так:

```
3rdParties -
            - MyAPIHeader.h
            - my.modulemap
```

мой файл modulemap выглядит так

```
module MyAPIHeader {
 header "MyAPIHeader.h"
 export *
}
```

и все работает хорошо, пока мне не нужно добавить еще один файл API в мою структуру modulemap, который не находится в том же каталоге.

```
anotherProjectDir -
                  - AnotherAPIHeader.h

3rdParties -
            - MyAPIHeader.h
            - my.modulemap
```

и мой файл modulemap выглядит так

```
module MyAPIHeader {
 header "MyAPIHeader.h"
 export *
}

module AnotherAPIHeader {
 header "AnotherAPIHeader.h"
 export *
}
```

а потом при попытке использовать функции AnotherAPIHeader у меня такая ошибка в файле modulemap

> Header 'AnotherAPIHeader.h' not found

Я пробовал указывать относительный путь (не заработало), потом указывать путь к хедеру в таргете (тоже не заработало)

Вывод: нет возможности указать в modulemap относительный путь к .h файлу который находиться в соседней папке, файл дожен лежать там же где и модульмап

Как указать относительный путь?